# Allocation of products in warehouse

Tags: python

The problem regards allocation of an inventory of products on shelves in a warehouse. The inventory consists of 62380 unique item numbers. Each item number has an inventory level and a category assigned.

The inventory level and category are not unique and can occur multiple times. The warehouse consists of 4 rooms each with a different amount of shelves capable of holding a different amount of item numbers.

Room 1: 557 shelves capable of each holding 386 items

Room 2: 1012 shelves capable of each holding 170 items

Room 3: 808 shelves capable of each holding 107 items

Room 4: 473 shelves capable of each holding 93 items

In total there are 2850 shelves, the shelves are indexed 1 to 2850.
Room 1, has shelf index 1 to 557
Room 2, has shelf index 558 to 1569
Room 3, has shelf index 1570 to 2377
Room 4, has shelf index 2378 to 2850

In total there are 423158 products, all shelves will not be filled.

The shelf with the lowest index must be filled first. The items must be allocated according to the index in the list, this means the items with the lowest index must be put on the shelf with the lowest index at all times.

The input data consists of three lists along with the provided info of shelves above. Below I have provided an example of 10 of the 62380 unique products. The elements with the same list index are connected. For instance item number 1129 has a current inventory level of 133 and the category is FF.

```
itemnumber = [1129, 2422, 3313, '4444e', 4334, 2293, '9394d', '2323c', 1244, 2142, ...]
currentinv = [133, 200, 231, 222, 212, 100, 234, 999, 656, 433, ...]
category = ['FF', 'SF', 'SF', 'SF', 'SN', 'SN', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN', ...]
```

As an example of the allocation 133 of item number 1129 will be assigned to shelf 1, 200 of item number 2422 will be assigned to shelf 1, 53 of item number 3313 will be assigned to shelf 1, shelf 1 is now full this means 178 of item number 3313 will be assigned to shelf 2, etc.

The output is wanted as a list of lists, showing the item number, amount stored of the specific itemnumber, the category of the item number, and what shelf the items has been stored on.

```
allocation = [[1129, 133, 'FF', 1], [2422, 200, 'SF', 1], [3313, 53, 'SF', 1], [3313, 178, 'SF', 2], ...]
```

My question is how can I assign products to each rack and ensure that no more than the specified capacity is assigned, while considering that some items carry over to one or multiple shelves, while taking the above limitations into account?

I have tried writing some code, but the results was not useful by any means because I have no education using python. This was an attempt for making it work for room 1, where the shelf capacity is 386.

```
itemnumber = [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 4334, 2293, 9394, 2323, 1244, 2142]
currentinv = [133,  200,  231,  222,  212,  100,  234,999,656,433]

category = ['FFast', 'SN', 'NN', 'SF', 'SF', 'SN', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN']
iteminfo = list(zip(itemnumber, currentinv, category))
iteminfo = [list(t) for t in iteminfo]
sumvalue = 0


holding = []
locationassignment = []
holdingsum = 0
excess = 0
excess_itemnumber = -1
excess_category = 1
excess_list = []
racknumber = 0
x = 386

for value in range(len(iteminfo)):
    holding.append(iteminfo[value])
    sumvalue = iteminfo[value][1] + sumvalue
    if sumvalue > x:
        racknumber = racknumber = racknumber + 1
        current = holding[-1][1]
        for i in range(len(holding) - 1):
            holdingsum = holdingsum + holding[i][1]
        holding[-1][1] = x - holdingsum - excess
        remainder_val = [holding][-1][-1][1]
        holding.append(racknumber)
        if excess > 0:
            if len(holding) > 1:
                excess_itemnumber = iteminfo[value - 1][0]
                excess_category = iteminfo[value - 1][-1]
            else:
                excess_itemnumber = iteminfo[value][0]
                excess_category = iteminfo[value][-1]
            excess_list.append(excess_itemnumber)
            excess_list.append(excess)
            excess_list.append(excess_category)
            holding.insert(0, excess_list)
            excess_list = []
        locationassignment.append(holding)
        excess = current - remainder_val
        holdingsum = 0
        holding = []
        sumvalue = excess
        if iteminfo[value] == iteminfo[-1] and excess > 0:
            holdforlistwhendone = []
            insertlistwhendone = []
            holdforlistwhendone.insert(0, excess_category)
            holdforlistwhendone.insert(0, excess)
            holdforlistwhendone.insert(0, excess_itemnumber)
            locationassignment.append(holdforlistwhendone)
            locationassignment.append(racknumber + 1)

print(locationassignment)
```

This gives me the output, which somewhat works for the first two shelves, but I am unable to comprehend what to do whenever a value is above 386, whenever a value carry over or switching to a new room.

```
[[[1129, 133, 'FF'], [2422, 200, 'SN'], [3313, 53, 'NN'], 1], [[3313, 178, 'NN'], ['4444e', 208, 'SF'], 2], [[2293, 14, 'SN'], [4334, 212, 'SF'], [2293, 100, 'SN'], ['9394d', 60, 'NN'], 3], [['9394d', 174, 'NN'], ['2323c', 212, 'NN'], 4], [['2323c', 787, 'NN'], [1244, -401, 'NN'], 5], [[1244, 1057, 'NN'], [2142, -671, 'NN'], 6], [1244, 1104, 'NN'], 7]
```

Comment: So, other than posting your homework here, what have you actually tried yourself?

Comment: I added what I have tried now, hope it helps

Comment: From your description and from looking at the desired output, it is possible to store different categories of items on the same shelf as well as split item qty's across multiple shelves, so long as the shelf with lowest index is filled to capacity be fore moving to next shelf. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. The lowest index items must also be used first

Answer (score -1):

This very much seems like a homework problem, so I'll try to provide some guidance without generating your solution outright. You didn't share how the room/shelf description input is actually provided, so I'll assume it's just a condensed description. For example:

```
[1, 557, 386]
[2, 1012, 170]
[3, 808, 107]
[4, 473, 93]
```

So we need to track some information as we go:

1. The current shelf index, `shelf_idx`
2. The remaining capacity of that shelf, `shelf_capacity`

Starting at shelf index 0 and item index 0, we can add all 133 items to the shelf, updating its remaining capacity to 253. We do the same for item 1, and shelf 0 is left with a capacity of 53.

When we reach item 2, we have more of this item than shelf 0 is able to hold. We place what we can on shelf 0, update the remaining quantity of item 2, and move to shelf 1. Then it's just a matter of repeating this process until all items are allocated.

Some things for you to consider:

- How can you use the current shelf index to determine the shelf capacity?
- What loop structure can you use so that you don't assign too many items to a shelf? You'll probably be checking both `shelf_capacity` and `currentinv[i]` pretty often.

Hopefully this helps, good luck!